# Access ASP Website running on localhost through LAN

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net website running on my computer through Visual Studio 2010.

```
localhost:14587/site/login.aspx
```

How do I access it from another? The two computers are connected via LAN.

I've tried accessing this URL on computer B:

```
192.168.255.1:14587/site/login.aspx
```

192.168.255.1 is computer A's IP address on LAN.

It does not work though.

EDIT:

Btw, I tried accessing this URL on computer A (where the website is running on):

```
192.168.255.1:14587/site/login.aspx
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Try Below: http://192.168.255.1/site/login.aspx

Comment: Still doesn't work. BTW, i tried accessing this URL on computer A (where the website is running) and it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share anything with this pc? if you can, check your firewall for this port, and if they haven't answer to you, run your website from your iis.

Comment: Check virtual directory in IIS is confugured or not ?

Comment: How do I do that? I don't even know if I have IIS. Thanks

Comment: How do I configure IIS? I tried accessing `192.168.255.1:14587/site/login.aspx` on computer A but it can't even reach it.

Comment: Start -> Run and type "inetmgr" and check IIS is installed or not.

Comment: No it's not installed. I can see IISExpress though.

Comment: So first u will have to install IIS and then create virtual directory.

Comment: did you install iis? or explain it at first?

Comment: Open your iis, expand your server on top, if you have default web site in `Sites` click on `advanced setting` in right of page and insert your path in `physical path`. also with `Bindings` you can add other port to your website. for test it, click on `restart` in manage website, then below it click on `Browse`. if you want to run your source code in iis, you must to add permission to the source folder. in properties of folder on security tab click edit and add full control to this user or use `every one` with full control. have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK, asp.net runs in its own server called ASP.NET Development Server.

as Scott Gu mentioned in his blog . [IIS and asp.net development server](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Visual Studio’s built-in ASP.NET Development Server (also known as “Cassini”) has the benefit of being light-weight and easy to quickly run.  It doesn’t listen on remote ports (which makes it easier to get approved (or many corporate security environments), works even when you are running under a non-administrator account, and doesn’t require a separate installation step.

So the option is

1. You need host it on IIS (by creating a vitual directory)  [IIS-> createing virtual directory](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Creating-IIS7-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-using-Internet-Information-Services-Manager.aspx)  to access it from other computer.
2. giving appropriate permission to access the contents.

Answer (score 0):

It would be my guess that you have a local firewall running on computer A.
You have two options:

1. Change the port the website is running to port 80, which is more likely to get through firewalls.
2. Open port 14587 to the local lan - this will depend on what firewall is being run

Comment: But I tried accessing `192.168.255.1:14587/site/login.aspx` on computer A and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

windows firewall has disable for this.If not then you try:

```
Start -> Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules
```

Find World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In) in the list and select to enable the rule. Change is pretty much immediate.